ExtJS restore state sorters bug for columns in column
I use ExtJS Classic 7.3.1.
Hi, tell me what to do, please
I found a bug - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3rlq
when restoring a state, if a column has a sorter and is located in another column, an error occurs.
at the same time, if the column is taken out separately (Type (OK SORTER)), then everything is restored perfectly.
actions:

sort by column Type (OK SORTER);
refresh the page - the restoration of the state should go fine, i.e. the sorting will be on the column from paragraph 1;
sort by Day column (BUG SORTER)
refresh the page - it will try to restore the state, but it will fall with an error
clear the ext-tree panel state in localStorage


You have to add the sorter to the subgrid.

Remove all sorters from your treepanel.

Create a custom column-type for your sub-columns

Create your own functionality for applyColumnState, getColumnState and sort
Ext.define('MyApp.SubColumn', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
xtype: 'subcolumn',
 applyColumnState: function...,
 getColumnState:   function...,
 sort:             function...

});


Now you can customize your column states as you like.
With a bit of tweaking you should be able to get it running.
